# Getting Fatal Error when Trying to Build GridDB Python Client

Tags: griddb

Fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory

I am trying to build the GridDB Python client (0.7.6) on CentOS 7.4 and I am getting the error src/griddb_python.cxx:176:11: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory I have researched this error and tried install sudo yum install python3-devel but this did not fix the problem.

GridDB: 4.5.0-37163 CE
Python: 3.7.9

Any ideas on how I can get this to compile?

Comment: Hey and welcome to SO! I'm just reviewing this question and no nothing about GridDB, but I'd suggest the following: Research or ask on Github whether they support your Python version since the Readme only lists Python 3.6 as compatible. (Try that, if possible.)
You may also edit your post to use Code tags for the error message and add a few linebreaks. (Make use of the preview function.) More details on your configure/build process could be helpful, too.

Good luck and feel free to post an answer yourself, if you find it!

Answer (score 0):

Install [python3.6](https://tecadmin.net/install-python-3-6-on-centos/) on your system and then edit the Makefile of your python_client and change the value of this variable and run 'make' again:

#Previous Value:

```
INCLUDES_PYTHON = $(INCLUDES)   \
            -I/usr/include/python3.6
```

#New Value:

```
INCLUDES_PYTHON = $(INCLUDES)   \
            -I/usr/include/python3.6m
```